# Transforming layouts of ol.geom.Geometry

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-3

I have for example code with error:

```
var multipoint = new ol.geom.MultiPoint([]); // XY layout
var point = new ol.geom.Point([2,3,0]) // XYZ layout
multipoint.appendPoint(point) // error
```

What is the best way to transform layouts? To prevent layout errors.

Answer (score 5):

You can set the geometry layout when constructing the geometry (see also [ol.geom.GeometryLayout](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.geom.html#GeometryLayout)):

```
var multipoint = new ol.geom.MultiPoint([], 'XYZ');
var point = new ol.geom.Point([2,3,0]);
multipoint.appendPoint(point);
```

If you'd want to convert a geometry with the layout 'XY' to 'XYZ', you would have to manually convert the coordinates and create a new geometry with the layout 'XYZ'.

Comment: Ok, it is not special function in OpenLayers library, to transform layouts?

Comment: No, AFAIK there is no special method for that.

Comment: Layouts are very confusing sometimes, if you combine vectors from multiple sources. Thanks.